# Custom Datepicker ExtJS

Tags: extjs

How can I add buttons (Months) inside ExtJS datepicker (e.g., Jan. Feb. etc..)

I know that there's a dropdown (Months) available but I need to add buttons for easy navigation between Months.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?229320-Date-Picker-Customization Here is a forum thread concerning the same thing. You should write your own extension.

Comment: Thanks but there is no given example on the thread.

Comment: There are a lot of guides on creating your own extensions/plugins/components. Like a funny presentation here http://www.slideshare.net/mankz/developing-components-and-extensions-for-ext-js